# May I shect a chicken with blade that is sharper than steel?

Tags: slaughter-shochet-shecht

As a schecting knife for poultry, may I substitute an instrument that cuts even faster, more sharply, and more humanely that a steel blade, such as a high power laser beam or water jet, both which can cut through even metal extremely fast?

Comment: AFAIK a laser burns, it doesn't cut. Your title asks about sharper blades but your post just mentioned different ways of killing an animal besides slicing with a blade

Comment: @sabbahillel isn’t this yours https://sabbahillel.blogspot.com/2011/08/if-you-shecht-with-light-saber-it.html?m=1

Comment: In what way is killing the chicken with a high power water jet more humane?

Comment: Not only was the item prescribed, but the usage as well. It needs a slicing motion, no pressing, etc. You will not satisfy those details.

Comment: It need not be "metal" per se, but it does have to be a very sharp solid doing cutting. Ceramics, for instance, are okay. You will not get a lot of sympathy from halachic traditionalists claiming any other method is "more humane."

Comment: You are allowed to schecht birds with a sharp thumbnail, so metal isn't a requirement.

Comment: I'm not wanting to be "more than humane". I'm wanting to be at least as humane, in other words, to make easier to do.